# How to calc rails models columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, real-time, calc

I have model Article.

migration file:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.string :body
      t.string :keyword
      t.integer :price
      t.integer :count_text
      t.integer :total_price
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have `ArticlesController` with two standard methods `new` and `create`

I did `new.html.erb` files and used form helpers.
But the field and count_text total_price need to generate automatically (price * count_text)
Count_text - is the size of the body line.
User input text in the body of the field, the text is calculated and then multiplied by the price and displayed to the user before confirmaton the creation of record. How to make it?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, especially the part after "But the ..". There are (at least) 2 aspects: compute on the fly on the client side (won't be done by rails), compute something in the controller (but only possible after submit). Could you clarify what you want?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how this can be done both ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, you want to display the total_price(count_text*price) before creation of a Article record.Calculating the total price on rails side would include an unnecessary server call because the user might cancel the article on seeing the price of the article. Your problem can be easily solved using javascript / jquery where you can write a small function to calculate to display the total amount.
lets say a put the amount on a label.
you can get some idea with this code below i guess:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo Article </title>
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtBody").focusout(
function()
{
var count, total_price;
count = $("#txtBody").val().length; // get length of the text in the textarea
total_price = count * $("#price").val(); // multiple with the price per character
$("#txtBody").after('<br><mark> Total Price : ' + total_price +"</mark>"); // display the total price
}
)
$("#txtBody").focus(
function()
{
$("mark").remove(); // removes the total price if the body id currently edited
}
)
});
</script>
<style>
mark {font-size:1.875em;color:white;background-color:#DC143C;}
</style>
<head>
<body>
Price: <input type="text" readonly="true" id="price" value="7")><br>
Body : <textarea cols="30" id="txtBody"> </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use virtual attributes for these two columns. If you're interested check [here](http://www.podcast.tv/video-episodes/16-virtual-attributes-14855462.html).

I'm a newbie myself, but I'm sure others can help you build the functions. Virtual attributes seem to be what you're looking for.